# iPhone App on iPad - What is the extra effort?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I started to develop an iPhone App for a client but the binary not yet submitted to Apple. My client asked me whether they can run the iPhone App also on the iPad. I am not sure what to answer. I am away from home and cannot even check how this all works in XCode. I wonder whether I have to submit two binaries two Apple - one for iPhone and one for iPad - or how this all works? If somebody with experience can explain me. Basically I need to figure out how much more effort I have to consider if it is only making the app work on the iPad. I do not mean the effort to redesign the whole app being a real "iPad app". Just to make it work and when somebody downloads the app and it can be for an iPhone and for an iPad and it does not matter.

Comment: You can create the Universal Application. You need to create separate xib file for iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iPhone app can run on an iPad anyway, but that's not a great experience (get your iPad out, download a free iPhone app, and try it). You could make a 'universal' application that works properly on both types of hardware, most of the code you've written will already work properly on the iPad side but you'll need new views and view controllers (and graphics).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the "user experience" aspect. In terms of administration effort. Is there any extra work in submitting the app (I never before submitted an app).

Comment: @hol Zero effort. Any iPhone app will work on an iPad (albeit not full screen) with zero modification from you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have well applied the MVC pattern, you only need to create new viewController made for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Got your question @hol.

that you dont wanna redesign the application for iPad but you want your application to run on iPad also.

iPhone applications can be installed in iPad and when we run it it gives 2X button in the right bottom corner which zooms the iPhone application in iPad. But the problem is it gives blur images as the images are zoome to double.

And the question that your client is asking whether it is iPad compatible or not then the answer is NO.

For making both iPhone and iPad compatible as mentioned above by all you have to develop universal application.

where either you have to make 2 nibs for each view controller..

Hope this helps..

hAPPY iCODING...